# C++ average letters debug assertion

Tags: c++

First let me start by saying I have read and searched the other topics and am still having an issue figuring out my problem. The program here uses a class and should take a string in and display the total number of characters and the average amount of characters per word. I am getting the Debug assertion failed error and am unable to debug it at that point. From what I have read, if I am calling `ispunct` or `isalnum` with an integer that is not a single byte I will throw this error, but I don't see why my program is getting this. It builds fine in VS, but once I enter my string, crash. Could anyone be so kind as to point out my error? I'm still pretty new at this so be gentle if my code is whack.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Cstring
{
private:
    int word;
    int punct;
    double allChars;
    double avg;
    char cstring[100];
    int index;
public:
    Cstring();
    void wordCount(char[], int&, double&, int&);
    double getAvg(int, int, double);
    void getInput();
    void setInput();
    void display();

};

Cstring::Cstring()
{
    word = 0;
    punct = 0;
    allChars = 0.0;
    avg = 0.0;
    index = 0;
}

void Cstring::getInput()
{
    char cstring[100];
    cout << "Enter your string: " << endl;
    cin.getline(cstring, 100);
    return;
}

void Cstring::setInput()
{
    getInput();
    wordCount(cstring, word, allChars, punct);
    avg = getAvg(word, punct, allChars);
    display();
}

void Cstring::display()
{
    cout << "\nThe number of words in that string: " << word << endl;
    cout << "\nAverage number of characters per word: " << fixed << 
        setprecision(2) << avg << "\n" << endl;
}

void Cstring::wordCount(char[], int&, double&, int&)
{
    while (cstring[index] != '\0')
    {
        if ((isspace(cstring[index])) || (ispunct(cstring[index]))) {
            while ((isspace(cstring[index])) || (ispunct(cstring[index]))) {
                index++;
            }
        }
        if ((isalnum(cstring[index])) || (ispunct(cstring[index]))) {
            word++;
            while ((isalnum(cstring[index])) || (ispunct(cstring[index]))) {
                index++;
                allChars++;
                if ((ispunct(cstring[index]))){
                    punct++;
                }
            }
        }
        index++;
    }
}

double Cstring::getAvg(int, int, double)
{
    allChars = allChars - punct;
    avg = (allChars / word);
    return avg;
}

int main()
{
    Cstring s1;

    s1.setInput();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you ensure that `cstring` has a terminating `'\0'` after `getline()`?

Comment: Also, your getInput function is saving the string to a local variable instead of your class variable.

Comment: @AnonMail how? Isn't it saving the string to the class variable `cstring`?

Comment: @still2blue you have a char cstring[100] variable locally defined in the getInput function which hides the class variable of the same name.

Comment: @AnonMail oops! Forgot to take that out after creating the class and implementing from main. Still getting the assertion error`

Comment: For that, please see the first comment posted here.

Comment: @AnonMail so that `\0` needs to be in my getline as such `cin.getline(cstring, 100, '\0');`?

Comment: @still2blue actually, I believe in your original code, the getline stores an ending '\0' if there is available space.

Comment: @AnonMail and in my`wordCount` function I test to be sure it's not at the ending `\0`. So confused as to why this thing wont run :(

Comment: Do you really need a class for this?  I would recommend doing this with free standing functions.

Comment: [OT] You may want to change your naming convention, as Microsoft code tends to prefix its classes with 'C', such as `CString`.

Comment: Why do you pass member variables to a member function, like `wordCount`?  All non-static member functions have direct access to class data members.

Comment: You don't need the loop for checking punctuation symbols or spaces.  All you need is to check for valid word characters.  The `++index` at the bottom of the loop takes care of advancing to the next character.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i do need it to be a class. So are you saying I should just use like `wordCount()` instead of declaring the params?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to pass parameters to `wordCount` since it uses the class variables.  See your other methods for an example.

Comment: All of your method definitions that have parameters need parameter names.  If you are not using the parameters that are passed, don't pass them.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews so basically none of them need parameters since they all have member access?

Answer (score 1):

Let us take one method to show common issues: `wordCount`.

### Don't pass member variables to member functions:

```
void Cstring::wordCount(char[], int&, double&, int&)
```

Also, if you need to pass parameters, they need names:

```
void Cstring::wordCount(char[] the_string,
                        int &word_count,
                        double &average,
                        int & whatever)
```

### Accessing Class Members directly:

In the code below, you are accessing the variables in the class from the method functions.  No need for them to be passed.

```
{
    while (cstring[index] != '\0')
    {
```

### Scanning for word characters:

The mechanics of the outer `while` loop is to increment the index and point to the character to test.

If the character is a *word* character, the perform the actions necessary, otherwise ignore it:

```
        if ((isalnum(cstring[index])) || (ispunct(cstring[index]))) {
            word++;
            allChars++;
            if ((ispunct(cstring[index]))){
                punct++;
            }
        }
        index++;
    }
}
```

### Return Statement Confusion

The `return` statement is only required when your function returns an object or value.  If your function declaration says `void function`, that means it returns nothing, so no `return` statement is necessary.

Comment: thank you for breaking this down. However even after making said changes, I still get the assertion error. Why is this happening?

Comment: Where is it happening?  Are you using a debugger or gambling and running the executable (hoping it works correctly)?

Comment: Well I am running it in VS2013 and either way I go, start with or without debugging, it brings up my console and when I type a string in and hit enter, I get the error

Comment: So, when you place breakpoints, which line causes the issue?  When you execute each statement, one at a time, and *watch* the variables, which statement causes the issue?

Comment: It is happening right at this line after the last word is read in as far as I can tell `if ((isspace(cstring[index])) || (ispunct(cstring[index]))) {`

Comment: I'm really impressed by the intelligence of people: [How to set a breakpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k80ex6de%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Search engines are wonderful tools, learn to use them.

Comment: Deleted that comment because I did google it. See other answer